# Mixed CSS scroll-snap-type?

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap, scroll-snap-type

Right now, CSS' `scroll-snap` feature allows `proximity` or `mandatory` `scroll-snap-type`. This makes either all children snapports snap according to the defined behaviour. Is there any way to incorporate mixed snap type - mandatory for some children and proximity for others?